# Big-oh time complexity for nested for loop

Tags: big-o

I have a question here the loop is:

```
for (i=0; i < n; ++i)
   for (j = 3; j < n; ++j)
           {
            ...
           }
```

I kind of understand how to calculate the big-oh but I am not entirely sure on how to do it.  The outer loop executes n times and the inner loop executes i times for each value of i. The complexity is supposed to be N^2 (I think). Can you guys elaborate on how this is calculated? I understand some of it but not all of it.

Comment: Are you sure you typed that out right? Did you mean "j = i"? Because this just executes n*(n-3) times.

Comment: I think your code is wrong – or your question is: the inner loop is supposed to read `for (j = 3; j < i; ++j)`, right? I.e. `j < i`, not `j < n`.

Comment: One probable mistake and two different solutions... I am excited to see how it goes on ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling - even if it's `j < i`, the complexity is still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @IVlad: yup, but the current answers fail to explain why. Care to write a better one?

Answer (score 9):

It is `(n*(n-3)) = n²-3n` and for very big `n` it is close to `n²`. So for Big-Oh notation I would write `O(n²)` because the `-3n` can be ignored.

---

Just a correction to your test in the question: the outer loop executes `n` times, the inner `(n-3)` times for each iteration on the outer loop.

Comment: Yes.  You always discard terms that are smaller than the highest order term when expressing O() notion.

Answer (score 4):

The complexity isn't necessarily O(n^2). It actually depends on what is going on in the "...". If the stuff in the inner loop has O(1) complexity, then yes, the overall complexity is O(n^2). 
The reason is because on any iteration of the outer loop you have n-3 iterations of the inner loop. Each iteration of the inner loop has 1 execution of the body, which we assume is O(1). So, you end up with n*(n-3) executions of the body. If we assume the body is O(1), then the complexity of the whole thing is O(n*(n-3)) = O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Remember what Crom said: it depends on what's in the ellipsis. I may be abusing the notation, but I think you could say that this is *O(mn<sup>2</sup>)*, where *m* is a function that bounds the growth of whatever is in the ellipsis (it could be related to *n*, but we don't know that).

You didn't ask this part specifically, but make sure that you're clear on why *n<sup>2</sup> - 3n* is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Look at the definition for big-O, which says that *n<sup>2</sup> - 3n ≤ cn<sup>2</sup>*, where *c* is a constant of our choosing. When *c = 2*, we can rewrite as *n<sup>2</sup> - 3n ≤ n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>*, which is clearly true.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the construct of nested for loops is O(n^2), but there are some exceptions.  In computer graphics, it is normal to see something like:

```
for (int x=0; x < width; x++) {
  for (int y=0; y < height; y++) {
    // Do something on a specific pixel in the image in constant time
  }
}
```

And see it called O(n) instead on O(n^2) because n is assumed to be the number of pixels in some contexts, instead of the linear size of the image.  So, the "n^2" is already taken into account.  There are probably other domain-specific contexts where the accepted definition of "n" may not be immediately obvious just from looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies, I can see now that the inner loop executes n-3 times due to j starting out as 3. The outer loop executes n times as usual. As for the people who were confused that I wrote the problem wrong, that is how the problem is given. I triple checked and its exactly how I wrote it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you can use Sigma Notation to obtain the exact number of iterations, and consequently determine the order of growth.

[image]